# How to achieve timeout handling in blocking DatagramChannel without using selectors

Tags: java, udp, nio, datagram

I get a feeling that I am missing something really obvious here.

The overall structure of my system makes me want to use a blocking DatagramChannel without Selectors, in order to keep things simple.
I am trying to achieve timeout handling by setting a timeout on the socket, but this seems to have no effect.

This pseudoized code gives a hint of what I am trying to achieve.

```
DatagramChannel channel = DatagramChannel.open();
channel.socket().bind(some address);
channel.socket().setSoTimeout(3000);
channel.send(outBuffer, peerAddress);

channel.receive(inBuffer);
```

On the other side, I have a UDP server that gives five quick responses, and then, for testing purposes, delays about five seconds before delivering the sixth response.

The delay does not trigger a SocketTimeoutException. Why is that? The timeout set on the socket does not seem to be taken into consideration when calling channel.receive.

Regards,
Fredrik

Comment: I've recently discovered that setSoTimeout() doesn't work for SocketChannel reads, and it looks like it doesn't work for DatagramChannels either. Why, I cannot imagine. Is there some reason you can't use a DatagramSocket?

Comment: No reason. Just thought DatagramChannel looks nicer.

Comment: It does, but it has this strange *lacuna.*

Comment: You should consider accepting one of the given answers.

Answer (score 7):

Apparently the issue of not being able to timeout is not a bug with DatagramChannel, but that:

> Not a bug.  The read methods in SocketChannel (and DatagramChannel) do not
> support timeouts.  If you need the timeout functionality then use the read
> methods of the associated Socket (or DatagramSocket) object.

[Link.](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4614802)

Comment: I have to agree with you there. I'm just learning SocketChannels myself so are we supposed to use a Selector instead?

Comment: Apparently, but that also forces you to use non-blocking mode. It remains bizarre. There is no reason for read timeouts not to be supported. A socket is a socket at the C layer.

Comment: This is quite strange, as the DatagramChannel doc says: Datagram channels support timeouts on read operations. If a datagram channel is in blocking mode, and a timeout period has been set by invoking its socket's setSoTimeout method, then a TimeoutException is thrown if a receive or read method is invoked but fails to complete before the timeout period expires.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I did:

## Create an `Interrupter` class

```
static private class Interrupter implements Runnable
{
    private final Thread th1;
    private volatile int wait=-1;
    private Interrupter(Thread ith1)
    {
        th1=ith1;
    }
    public void run()
    {
        while(true)
        {
            try{
                if( wait<0 ){ th1.join(); break; }
                else{ Thread.sleep(wait); th1.interrupt(); wait=-1; }
            } catch(Exception e){}
        }
    }
}
```

## Setup the `Interrupter`

```
Interrupter ir1=new Interrupter(Thread.currentThread());
Thread th1=new Thread(ir1);
th1.start();
// We need this so that later the wait variable
// can be passed in successfully
while( th1.getState()!=Thread.State.WAITING );
```

## Use the `Interrupter`

```
try{
    ir1.wait=waitTimeout;
    th1.interrupt();
    // Receive on the socket
    dc2.receive(bb2);
} catch(ClosedByInterruptException e){
    // (Timed out)
    Thread.interrupted();
    dc2.close();
    // Handle timeout here
    // ...
    // We need this so that later the wait variable
    // can be passed in successfully
    while( th1.getState()!=Thread.State.WAITING );
}
// Received packet
ir1.wait=-1;
th1.interrupt();
// We need this so that later the wait variable
// can be passed in successfully
while( th1.getState()!=Thread.State.WAITING );
Thread.interrupted();
```